# Show that $D=\{t\in \mathbb{R}:P\left(x\in E:~f(x)=t\right)>0\}$ is at most countable.

Tags: probability-theory

Let $(E,\mathcal{E},\rho)$ be an arbitrary metric space, with $\mathcal{E}$ being the smallest $\sigma$-algebra containing the open subsets of $E$ induced by the metric $\rho$. Let $f:E\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a **continuous** and **bounded** real-valued function defined on $E$. Suppose $P$ is a probability measure defined on the measurable space $(E,\mathcal{E})$. Show that the set

\begin{align}
D = \{t\in \mathbb{R}:P\left(x\in E:~f(x)=t\right)>0\}
\end{align}

is at most countable.

Any hints on solving this problem will be of help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For each $t\in \mathbb{R}$, let
$$
E_t = \{x\in E : f(x) = t\} = f^{-1}(\{t\})
$$
For $n\in \mathbb{N}$, let
$$
D_n = \{t \in \mathbb{R} : P(E_t) > 1/n\}
$$
Then it is clear that $$D = \bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} D_n$$ and so it suffices to show that each $D_n$ is a finite set. In fact, we claim that
$$
|D_n|< n
$$
To see this, note that the $E_t$ are all mutually disjoint, hence if $\{t_1,t_2,\ldots, t_{n+1}\} \subset D_n$, we have
$$
1 = P(E) \geq P(\sqcup_{i=1}^{n+1} E_{t_i}) = \sum_{t=1}^{n+1} P(E_{t_i}) > \frac{n+1}{n}
$$
which is a contradiction. This proves the claim and with it, the result you seek.

Comment: Thank you so much for the detailed explanation.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** Since $P$ is a probability measure, the set

$$D_{k} := \left\{t \in \mathbb{R}; P(x \in E; f(x)=t) \geq \frac{1}{k} \right\}$$ is finite. Thus, $$D = \bigcup_{k \in \mathbb{N}} D_k$$ is at most countable.

Comment: @AGuyWhoWantsToSucceed You are welcome.